# Unzip gzip files in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am wondering if it is possible to set up a source and sick in ADF that will unzip a gzip file and shows the extracted txt file. What happened is that the sink was incorrectly defined where both the source/sink had gzip compression.

So what ended up is that "fil1.gz" is now "file1.gz.gz".

This is how the file looks in Azure blob:
[image]

This is how the file looks like in an S3 bucket (the end is cut off, but the end is "txt.gz"):
[image]

I saw that in COPY there is Zipdeflate and deflate compression, but I get an error that it does not support this type of activity.

I created a sink in an ADF pipeline where I am trying to unzip it. In the datasource screen I used Zipdeflate, but it puts the file name with "deflate" extention, and not with the 'txt'.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us more about your setting steps or screenshots?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue I have added more details on how the files look and what I am trying to do. Please let me know if the above helps.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/92973/extract-files-from-targz-files-store-in-blob-conta.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a "copy data" object
Source:
as your extenstion is gz, you should choose GZip as compresion type, tick binary copy
Target:
Blob Storage Binary
compresion- none

Such copy pipeline will unzip your text file(s)

Comment: thank you @ArunasB. I have tried that however for some reason the files came out corrupted. I did do this with a dummy file and the results came out without issues. I had just asked for new files, but will keep this in mind next time I encounter this.